# Здравствуйте. Не получается сделать анимацию в задании в книге на 386 стр. : макфарланд новая большая книга css

Tags: css, анимация

Само задание [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В книге в теории говорилось создать ключевые кадры, я их сделал, но видимо есть ошибка

```css
@-webkit-keyframes gallery {
    from {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px  rgb(221, 160, 221);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px  rgb(240, 230, 140);
    }
}

@keyframes gallery {
    from {
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px  rgb(221, 160, 221);
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px  rgb(240, 230, 140);
    }
}
```

для большего приоретета создал огромный селектор потомков nav li a .gallery:hover и в HTML коде создал класс gallery к тегу a `<li><a class="gallery" href="#">Галерея</a></li>`но анимация всеравно не воспроизводится при наведении указателя мыши поверх кнопки, что я сделал не правильно? Может механизм каскадности нарушил и из-за этого не срабатывает? Спасибо!

```html
nav li a .gallery:hover {
        -webkit-animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
        animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
    }
```

HTML код из книги поэтому должен быть верным, я только `<a class="gallery">` добавил чтобы воздействовать именно на эту ссылку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот CSS код который из учебника я лишь добавил ключевые кадры и анимацию, пример кода которой есть в моём вопросе. Спасибо если кто-то этим поинтересуется)

```css
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

header {
    background: rgb(255,214,94); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(100,100,100),rgb(0,0,0));  
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 10px 0 30px 0; 
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;    
}
header h1 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

nav {
    margin-left: 200px; 
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}



nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #ff932d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #c95e00;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 1px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

/* пользовательские стили  */
nav a {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s,
                      background-color 1s ease-in .5s;
  transition: transform .5s,
              background-color 1s ease-in .5s;
}



nav a:hover {
    background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
    animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
}



@-webkit-keyframes logo {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) scale(.5);
    left: 120%;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-720deg) scale(.5);
    left: 0;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes logo {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0) scale(.5);
    left: 120%
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(-720deg) scale(.5);
    left: 0;
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
  }
}

.logo {
    -webkit-animation: logo 3s;
    animation: logo 3s;
}

/*вот это моя попытка сделать ключевые кадры и анимацию*/
@-webkit-keyframes gallery {
    from {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px  rgb(221, 160, 221);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px  rgb(240, 230, 140);
    }
}

@keyframes gallery {
    from {
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px  rgb(221, 160, 221);
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px  rgb(240, 230, 140);
    }
}
nav li a .gallery:hover {
    -webkit-animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
    animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
}
```

Comment: Все должно работать... Выложи `HTML`

Comment: @Air Сейчас дополню свой вопрос полным HTML и CSS кодом который у меня есть, в основном этот код полностью из книжки Макфарладна, моя же часть всего лишь ключевые кадры с именем gallery и анимация с таким же именем

Comment: @Air Ты пишешь, что нужно создать границы к этому селектору класса  .gallery 
но в CSS коде который я выложил уже есть в селекторе потомков nav a {} свойство границ вот такое  border: 1px solid #c95e00; или всеравно есть смысл сделать как ты сказал?

Comment: Во-первых граница нужна для визуальной ориентации "куда наводить мышь", во-вторых не вижу HTML

Comment: @Air HTML прикреплен в виде фотки в моём вопросе, наверное не очень удобно получилось(

Answer (score 1):

```css
.gallery {
       width:500px;
       height:500px;
       border:1px solid red;
    }

.gallery:hover {
        animation: gallery 3s linear 3 alternate;
    }
@keyframes gallery {
    from {
        box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 3px  rgb(221, 160, 221);
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 85px  rgb(240, 230, 140);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery"></div>
```